# server socket listening on client vs polling service for android instant messenger app

Tags: java, android, mysql, sockets, kotlin

i am currently writing an instant messenger application for android as well as the server app that i am running off of my laptop. the server app connects to an sql database (on the same machine) and verifies login info, creates new accounts, inserts other conversation info into the db. so far all of this is working however i need to decide on a strategy for how i am going to pass the sent messages from the server to the desired recipient.

what i have so far:

1. the client connects to the server and sends the message info including sender, recipient and message
2. the server stores the info in the db and sends a response indicating success or failure to the sender client
3. the sender client updates its views to reflect any changes in db or to indicate failure

now i have two different ideas for how to approach the delivery of the messages to the recipient

A. create a service in the android app that polls the server for changes in the db

B. create a server socket in the android app that listens for connection requests from the server and have the server attempt to send every new update to the client

please let me know of some of the pros and cons of these approaches or if their is maybe something better that i have not mentioned. also, i am mainly using java for this, but with some kotlin code, if that makes any difference. i am a self taught programmer that is doing this for practice and it is really growing to be a massive project in comparison to anything that i have done before. i would greatly appreciate any help that is given. thank you.

Comment: Why not establish a two way pipe on initial connection?

Comment: @Boris I guess I don't really know much about that. But I will look into it.

Comment: A websocket would be easiest - stick STOMP on it and you have two way event driven comms. Of course you could build something more exotic, but I'm not sure it's worth it.